# MLR OLS computing slope and intercept separately

Tags: regression, least-squares

In multiple linear regression, when we want to derive the slopes and intercept separately, I have seen the following formulas:

$\hat \beta = (X^T_c X_c)^{-1} X^T_c y_c$

$\beta_0 = \overline y - \beta^T \overline x$

where $X_c$ is the centered $X$ matrix $(x_{m} - \overline x_m)$.

My question is, if we solve for the intercept and slopes separately, why do we need to center the data?

If we derive the solution from the MSE:

$\text{MSE} = (y - X\beta - \beta_0)^T (y - X\beta - \beta_0)$

I get that the solutions to the slopes is the habitual:

$\beta = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T y$

Do you get a different result? Can you explain mathematically why this is?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "solve ... separately"?  Exactly what operation or algorithm would that be?

Comment: I mean finding the value of the intercept by taking the derivative of this expression w.r.t. $\beta_0$ and finding the value of the other coefficients by computing the gradient of the expression w.r.t. $w$.

Comment: I doubt it can be done that way generally.  You will need edit your question to show what you mean.

Comment: In a couple of textbooks they show that the results are the formulas I have in the question, so it's definitely possible. Software libraries like scikit-learn also find the parameters this way. What I am interested in, is the derivation of these formulas.

Comment: I really can't tell what you mean by "definitely possible."  The algorithmic solutions to most matrix equations are generally developed one variable at a time -- but so what?  As far as getting different results goes, that's possible only when the design matrix $X$ is rank-deficient.

Comment: I mean exactly this: from the definition of the OLS cost function it is possible to find the intercept of the model and the rest of the parameters separately, i.e. without adding a bias column to X and solving for the aggregate $\beta$ parameters. Several textbooks say it is indeed possible and show that the resulting formulas are the ones I pasted in my question. How to get to those results from the original OLS expression? That is what I am trying to find out by asking this question.